# Whats the difference between <[]> vs <null>

Tags: java, collections, junit, set

```
<[]> vs <null>
```

The first is an empty set containing no objects. It can be created from the code:

```
Set<Node> expected =new HashSet<>();
```

The second could be a set containing 1 null element. If not, can null really have a type `Set`?

Not sure how to code the second item.

Comment: `null` is **not** an object. It's a reference pointing nowhere and can have  **referential** type of any object. It occupies a memory slot on the Stack but nothing on the Heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<[]> means an object include no elements. null is not an element.
after u call Structure method like `new HashSet<>();`, set point to a real memory. But null point to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

A set containing `null` contains the element `null`. An empty set does not contain the element `null`.

Suppose you make a set containing `null` like this:

```
Set<Object> setWithNull = new HashSet<Object>();
setWithNull.add(null);
```

And an empty set like this:

```
Set<Object> emptySet = new HashSet<Object>();
```

Then you can see the following differences:

```
setWithNull.size()==1                   emptySet.size()==0
setWithNull.isEmpty()==false            emptySet.isEmpty()==true
setWithNull.contains(null)==true        emptySet.contains(null)==false

setWithNull.equals(emptySet)==false
```

So a set containing `null` is different from an empty set in many significant ways.

Comment: Does the set actually contain null, even without the square brackets `<[null]>` vs `<null>`?

Comment: @user83039 I don't know what you are imagining that you do meaningfully with these square brackets. You can create a set and put `null` in it without typing a square bracket.

Comment: These are values in JUnit.

Comment: There is nothing in your question about JUnit. If you have a question about JUnit, post that.